# Volume of revolution of solid formed by $ y = x^2 $ and $ y=2x $ about $y$-axis

Tags: integration, solid-of-revolution

I am trying to find the volume of revolution of solid formed by $ y = x^2 $ and $ y=2x $ about the $ y $-axis where both graphs lie in the **first quadrant** only.

The graph is shown below:

[image: Graph of $y=x^2$ and $y=2x$]

Since it is a rotation about the $y$-axis, let's express $x$ in terms of y instead.

Hence, $ y = x^2 $ becomes $ x = \sqrt{y} $   (first quadrant only) and $ y = 2x $ becomes $ x = \frac{y}{2} $

Now, we will integrate with respect to y to obtain the volume of revolution:

1. Find points of intersection:

\begin{align} \text{ Let } x = \sqrt{y} = \frac{y}{2} \end{align}
\begin{align} \sqrt{y} = \frac{y}{2} \end{align}
\begin{align} y = \frac{y^2}{4} \end{align}
\begin{align} y^2 - 4y = 0 \end{align}
\begin{align} \therefore \ y = 4 \text{ or } y = 0 \end{align}

2. Integrate with respect to y

\begin{align}
\text{Volume of revolution}
&= \int_{0}^{4}{\pi\left(\sqrt{y}-\frac{y}{2}\right)^2}dy \\
&= \int_{0}^{4}{\pi\left[y-y\sqrt{y}+\frac{y^2}{4}\right]}dy \\
&= \pi\left[\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{2y^\frac{5}{2}}{5}+\frac{y^3}{12}\right]_0^4 \\
&= \pi\left[\frac{16}{2}-\frac{64}{5}+\frac{64}{12}\right] \\
&= \pi\left[\frac{160}{12}-\frac{64}{5}\right] \\
&= \pi\left[\frac{40}{3}-\frac{64}{5}\right] \\
&= \frac{8}{15}\pi \\
\end{align}

Somehow, the answer appears to be $ \frac{8}{3}\pi $ which was supposedly obtained by integrating with respect to $x$. Now, this leaves me puzzled. Shouldn't the volume produced be the same since the area bounded between the graphs are the same with respect to $x$-axis and $y$-axis?

Could someone please advise me on what went wrong here?

Comment: You should not take the difference. Calculate each volume Separately and then take the difference.

Comment: The volume of revolution is $\pi \int R^2 - r^2 dy$ not $\pi \int (R - r)^2 dy$  Where $R$ is the outer radius and $r$ is the inner radius of your washer.

Comment: @DogM Oh. I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my previous comment (now deleted) I should have pulled out the $\pi$ that is $\pi\int_{0}^{4}{\left(\sqrt{y}\right)^2-\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2}dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

volume of revolution=

$$\int_0^4 \pi ( (\sqrt{y})^2-(\frac{y}{2})^2)dy$$

= difference between the two volumes.

you will find

$\pi \frac{8}{3}$.